# How to make several list which have a name already decided variable

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list.`x=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Using this, I want to make 4 lists with names a, b, c, d

How can I do using `for` loop and `x=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`  ?

Comment: Explain your problem and desired output in more detail.

Comment: If you want 4 empty lists, use `a,b,c,d = [[] for _ in range(4)]`

Comment: try `for i in x:` instead of `--̶i̶f̶-̶i̶-̶i̶n̶-̶x̶:̶-̶`

Comment: I want to create a new empty list with names for each of the elements in another list( x=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
>>> x=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> di={k:[] for k in x}
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants `a=[]` instead of `'a'=[]`. I must say, the problem is unclear though